# Major differences between Drupal-6 and Pressflow-6?

Tags: 6

I am having a Drupal-6 site and was considering to scale it. I came across [Pressflow](http://pressflow.org/) and was wondering about the major differences between the two. I came across a similar question of Drupal-7 vs Pressflow-7 but was looking specifically for Drupal-6 vs Pressflow-6. Can anyone enlighten or share their experience of using both.

Comment: Did you look at this? http://pressflow.org/faq

Comment: @PatrickKenny I did look at the faq but could not find much other than "integration with Varnish and allows for MySQL replication". I was not sure if this is only the difference.

Comment: I am closing this question as the list of differences between Drupal 6, and Pressflow 6 is not a finite list. Pressflow 6 contains code that has been ported to Drupal 7, and there could be Drupal 7 code that is ported to Pressflow 6. Pressflow 6 is still under development.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at [the wiki: "Comparison - Pressflow versus Drupal"](https://pressflow.atlassian.net/wiki/display/PF/Comparison+-+Pressflow+versus+Drupal).

Comment: Thanks for the link. Can't vote your answer up but would surely request others to do it. Any link to the performance improvement or benchmarks between the two?